# Handling many customers in the "Manage Customers" admin page

Tags: customer-grid

I'm currently migrating about 330,000 customer records for a new client, and what I've found is that the "Manage Customers" Grid will slow to a crawl whenever you try to apply any sort of sorting on the grid.

I've dug through queries being made for this grid, and found that when a sort is applied, a temp table is created and sorted through, which causes the query to take a couple minutes to run, and create a ~3G temp table in the MySQL tmp directory.

An easy solution is to disable sorting for this grid, but I was wondering if anyone has been able to make the grid work with sorting for this many customer records?

EDIT: Here's the query being used by the "Manage Customers" page:

> SELECT `e`.*, 
>   `at_prefix`.`value` AS `prefix`, 
>   `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`, 
>   `at_middlename`.`value` AS `middlename`, 
>   `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`, 
>   `at_suffix`.`value` AS `suffix`, 
>   CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '', 
>   LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ''), 
>   LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), 
>   IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '', 
>   LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ''), 
>   LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)), 
>   IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '', 
>   LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value)), '')) AS `name`, 
>   `at_default_billing`.`value` AS `default_billing`, 
>   `at_billing_postcode`.`value` AS `billing_postcode`, 
>   `at_billing_city`.`value` AS `billing_city`, 
>   `at_billing_telephone`.`value` AS `billing_telephone`, 
>   `at_billing_region`.`value` AS `billing_region`, 
>   `at_billing_country_id`.`value` AS `billing_country_id`, 
>   `credit_tbl`.*, 
>   IFNULL(credit_tbl.`value`, 0) AS `credit_value` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_prefix` ON (`at_prefix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_prefix`.`attribute_id` = '4')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_middlename` ON (`at_middlename`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_middlename`.`attribute_id` = '6')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_suffix` ON (`at_suffix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_suffix`.`attribute_id` = '8')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing` ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode` ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city` ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_telephone` ON (`at_billing_telephone`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_telephone`.`attribute_id` = '31')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_region` ON (`at_billing_region`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_region`.`attribute_id` = '28')
>    LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id` ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')
>    LEFT JOIN `customercredit_credit` AS `credit_tbl` ON credit_tbl.customer_id = e.entity_id WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` DESC LIMIT 20

EDIT2: Here are the indexes currently being used on the `customer_entity` table:

> Table Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
>   customer_entity 0   PRIMARY 1   entity_id   A   333393  NULL    NULL        BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID    1   store_id    A   8   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID  1   entity_type_id  A   6   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID    1   email   A   333393  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID    2   website_id  A   333393  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID  1   website_id  A   8   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
>   customer_entity 1   IDX_created_at  1   created_at  A   333393  NULL    NULL        BTREE

EDIT3: It's a little messy, but I outputted the EXPLAIN to a file and copied it here:

> id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
>   1 SIMPLE  e   ref IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID  IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID  2   const   165978  Using
>   temporary; Using filesort
>   1 SIMPLE  at_prefix   eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_firstname    eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_middlename   eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_lastname eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_suffix   eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_default_billing  eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.e.entity_id,const  1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_billing_postcode eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.at_default_billing.value,const 1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_billing_city eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.at_default_billing.value,const 1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_billing_telephone    eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.at_default_billing.value,const 1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_billing_region   eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.at_default_billing.value,const 1
>   1 SIMPLE  at_billing_country_id   eq_ref  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_VALUE  UNQ_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID  6   fredericks_store.at_default_billing.value,const 1
>   1 SIMPLE  credit_tbl  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1

Comment: Sounds like an index would be helpful. Have you tried that?

Comment: Will you post the query used? Maybe we can optimize it.

Comment: Query looks good, you should take a look at MySQL's `IFNULL` method for the `name` column. Remove `credit_tbl.*` if not all columns are needed.

Comment: Well Vernard, the thing I'm trying to point out is that I'm not the one writing this query, it's generated by Magento by default for the "Manage Customers" grid.  It's not performing slow because of the extra columns, it's performing slow because of the sorting being done on the temp table (see EXPLAIN above).

Comment: A printscreen would've been better :P I can barely read it

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, if there's a way I can send it to you as a file it's probably more readable... printscreen won't be much better in my case

Answer (score 0):

Best case would be an index is used for the sorting. Try MySQL's `EXPLAIN` command and optimize away.

I can't help without your query and the information from the `EXPLAIN` from your database.

You might be interested in changing the following system variables which may affect `ORDER BY` speed.

- Increase the sort_buffer_size variable value.
- Increase the read_rnd_buffer_size variable value.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

EDIT:

Remove the `entity_type_id` from the condition, since you're already querying at `customer_entity`. I know it's magento code, but try to find out how this condition was added and remove it if you can.

Comment: Thanks Vernard, yes indexing was my first instinct.  I edited my post to include the query and the indexes for the `customer_entity` table.  I would post the EXPLAIN but the formatting is verbose and awful, so if you know a better way to post that then I'll add that as well.

Comment: My intuition is that indexing may not be useful here, as what I'm getting from doing an EXPLAIN is that temporary table is being created, and then a sort is being applied after.  

I deliberately sorted on the entity_id in the above query to illustrate that, as the entity_id is already indexed within its table.

Comment: I'm assuming that Magento is capable of handling thousands of customers within its EAV Database structure, right?

Comment: So if you apply sorting on any column except entity_id, it becomes slow?

Comment: You can increase the command line's screen buffer size so that `EXPLAIN` output becomes readable. Open `cli -> right click on menu -> properties` to change screen buffer size

Comment: Even with the entity_id it's slow.  It takes about a minute and a half for the query to run with sorting.  Without, it finishes within seconds, so it's definitely doing some sort of full table sort. 

i was curious if you or others have had experience with running a large customer data set in Magento, as it seems like the queries generated for the "Manage Customers" page don't perform well once there's enough records.

Comment: And just to add, these aren't queries that I've written, it's what's generated by Magento for its this Customer Grid.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` command will help us determine if there is a full table sort used, but since `entity_id` is a key, i'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have though initially as well, but that's not the case in this instance... that's what I'm talking about earlier.  I've seen the EXPLAIN, and what I'm figuring is that indexing the Magento tables involved won't help with performance because a temp table is generated whenever the ORDER clause is present.  Temp table is created, then sort is applied, and I don't think I get a chance to apply any sort of indexing to the temp table.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try that.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, so I think the EXPLAIN tells me that a temp table and sorting is still applied, but taking out the WHERE `e`.`entity_id` = `1` seems to improve the performance a lot when I actually run the query.  I'm going to play with this a bit, and I also want to rerun it on the full dataset (I cleared the DB working on something else).  I'll update this later, but thanks for all your help thus far Vernard!

Comment: Of course sorting is still in it, but if you sort it by `entity_id` which is the primary key, you shouldn't have any issue.

Removing the condition `entity_type_id` is the only thing that EXPLAIN gave to me. If you think I have helped you answer the question, please set my answer as the accepted answer. You're welcome